# How to reduce Firebase reads in a flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to develop a ride-sharing application using Firebase and Flutter. I am having issues with how to reduce the amount of reads on Firebase. I have a number of questions and would appreciate help for further clarity.

1. From the Firebase docs it stated you are charged for reads **only when the data is updated**. In theory, if I have a stream builder that reads from a document collection, does this mean I would be charged for a read if only data is updated in that collection? If this is true, if I have a button to show available nearby riders say 10, for a user to pick from, am I charged every time the user makes a search for riders or only if there's an update? example price.
2. I have read articles that state it is better to call streams from initState rather than the build method, as it helps reduce reads. is this true and could you explain this?
3. Are there ways to reduce reads overall to save costs

I normally use the stream builder directly in my build method and although most projects are not commercial, I really haven't noticed any reads like that. But this is my first commercial project and I am scared about billings.

Comment: Firebase charge for each read and write, but firebase provides automatic offline support for short period of time, also you will charged everytime you request data from firebase no matter document is updated or not.

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: What is important that you should create the stream itself in `initState` or somewhere else, but not in the `build` method; after this you set the `stream` of `StreamBuilder` to this already created stream. Otherwise the stream will be re-created on every build and this could occur many-many times. It is worth adding a `debugPrint` to the `build` method to see how often this is called by Flutter engine.

Comment: @PeterKoltai: Sounds like answwer! 
Moses: please limit yourself to a single question per post going forward.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I agree, the multiple questions were the reason why I haven't posted an answer. My comment covers only a part.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. Sorry for the multiple questions